# Как прибавить остаток скидки (30р) от второго товара к первому товару?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с покупками `positionName nvarchar(150), positionCost numeric(10,2)`.

И нам дана скидка `@discount int = 100`. Надо её равномерно распределить по всем позициям. То есть условно:

Товар 1 / 200руб / 50
Товар 2 / 20 руб / 50

Стоимость второго товара ниже чем сама скидка
Сделал такой запрос:

```
DECLARE @discount DECIMAL(10, 2) = 100;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, @discount / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pokupki) AS sk
    FROM pokupki
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN sk > positioncost THEN positioncost
            ELSE sk
       END AS skidka
FROM cte;
```

Получаем:

Товар1, цена:200, скидка:50р
Товар2, цена:20р, скидка:20р

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: *Надо её равномерно распределить по всем позициям.* Дайте точное определение термина "равномерно". Как по мне, пропорциональное распределение больше соответствует духу термина.

Comment: @Akina Да, вы правы

Comment: @Akina но на данном этапе нужно равными долями размазать.

Comment: Наиболее разумным считаю рекурсивный CTE. Начинаем с самого дешёвого товара (или товаров). Накидываем им среднюю скидку. Если многовато - берём для них обнуляющую скидку. На следующем витке обрабатываем следующие по стоимости товары, раскидывая в них откорректированный с учётом уже предоставленной на обработанный ранее товар размер общей скидки. И так далее.

Comment: Можно попробовать пропорционально ``=@discount/sum(positionCost)*positionCost``. На повторном проходе проверить и скинуть куда-либо (например на наибольшую строку), получившиеся копейки от округления.